# How can I sort an indirect array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, sorting

In my project, I need to sort an array that contain index of an other array (it's item). I've search for many hours, but I did not find anyone with my problem.

```
var arr = [1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
function sorting(){
    let arr2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    //sorting code
}
```

Now, I want to sort arr2, so when I loop through it with this kind of code (under this paragraph), I access arr with the index in the sorted array (arr2).

```
  arr[arr2[i]]
```

My first move was to use arr2.sort(function(a,b){arr[a] - arr[b]}, but each time the sort wasn't good. I attempt to make my own sorting function, but my problem stayed.

To summarize, I want to sort arr2 so when I loop through it, I get the value of arr in ascending (or descending) order.

**EDIT** I fixe this problem, but another appears, when I applied the arr2 on my html, the order mess up.

```
    var arr = [1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    function sorting(){
        let arr2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
        //The sorting block code (done)
        z = document.getElementsByClassName("triable"); //this is on what I applied arr2
        for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++){
            z[i].style.order = arr2[i]; //this line work, but doesn't correctly do what I what it to do
        }
    }
```

For html, I have some div with a class "triable" and the code above this need to applied a css style (order) so the div visually change of position

Comment: How should the output look like?

Comment: In ascending sort, all is good, but in descending sort, it give me this :
[9, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 4, 1]
when it is supposed to give me :
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1]

Comment: please add the complete code. otherwise your data unclear.

Comment: Nina Scholz, here is the "complete code" (I put your part of code in the sorting block code)

Answer (score 2):

**functional arbitrary sort**

Here's another way to approach your problem. Let's say we have some `fruits` and an arbitrary `order` we wish to sort them in -

```js
const fruits =
  //   0        1          2        3         4 
  [ "apple", "banana", "cherry", "orange", "peach" ]
  

const order =
  [ 1, 3, 2, 0, 4 ]
```

We want to be able to write something like this -

```js
fruits.sort(sortByIndex(fruits, order))

console.log(fruits)
// [ "banana", "orange", "cherry", "apple", "peach" ]
//      1         3         2         0        4
```

We wish up a `Comparison` module to handle our sorting code -

```js
const { empty, map } =
  Comparison
  
const sortByIndex = (values = [], indexes = []) =>
  map(empty, x => indexes.indexOf(values.indexOf(x)))
```

Now we just have to implement `Comparison` -

```js
const Comparison =
  { empty: (a, b) =>
      a < b ? -1
        : a > b ? 1
          : 0
  , map: (m, f) =>
      (a, b) => m(f(a), f(b))
  }

const { empty, map } =
  Comparison

const sortByIndex = (values = [], indexes = []) =>
  map(empty, x => indexes.indexOf(values.indexOf(x)))

const fruits =
  [ "apple", "banana", "cherry", "orange", "peach" ]
  //   0        1          2        3         4 
  
const order =
  [ 1, 3, 2, 0, 4 ]

console.log(fruits)
// [ "apple", "banana", "cherry", "orange", "peach" ]

console.log(fruits.sort(sortByIndex(fruits, order)))
// [ "banana", "orange", "cherry", "apple", "peach" ]
```

---

**why a module?**

Implementing a `Comparison` module means we have a tidy place to store all of our comparison logic. We could easily implement other useful functions like `reverse` and `concat` now -

```js
const Comparison =
  { // ...
  , concat: (m, n) =>
      (a, b) => Ordered.concat(m(a, b), n(a, b))
  , reverse: (m) =>
      (a, b) => m(b, a)
  }

const Ordered =
  { empty: 0
  , concat: (a, b) =>
      a === 0 ? b : a
  }
```

Now we can model complex sorting logic with ease -

```js
const sortByName =
  map(empty, x => x.name)

const sortByAge =
  map(empty, x => x.age)

const data =
  [ { name: 'Alicia', age: 10 }
  , { name: 'Alice', age: 15 }
  , { name: 'Alice', age: 10 }
  , { name: 'Alice', age: 16 }
  ]
```

Sort by `name` then sort by `age` -

```
data.sort(concat(sortByName, sortByAge))
// [ { name: 'Alice', age: 10 }
// , { name: 'Alice', age: 15 }
// , { name: 'Alice', age: 16 }
// , { name: 'Alicia', age: 10 }
// ]
```

Sort by `age` then sort by `name` -

```js
data.sort(concat(sortByAge, sortByName))
// [ { name: 'Alice', age: 10 }
// , { name: 'Alicia', age: 10 }
// , { name: 'Alice', age: 15 }
// , { name: 'Alice', age: 16 }
// ]
```

And effortlessly `reverse` any sorter. Here we sort by `name` then reverse sort by `age` -

```js
data.sort(concat(sortByName, reverse(sortByAge)))
// [ { name: 'Alice', age: 16 }
// , { name: 'Alice', age: 15 }
// , { name: 'Alice', age: 10 }
// , { name: 'Alicia', age: 10 }
// ]
```

**functional principles**

Our `Comparison` module is flexible yet reliable. This allows us to write our sorters in a formula-like way -

```js
// this...
concat(reverse(sortByName), reverse(sortByAge))

// is the same as...
reverse(concat(sortByName, sortByAge))
```

And similarly with `concat` expressions -

```js
// this...
concat(sortByYear, concat(sortByMonth, sortByDay))

// is the same as...
concat(concat(sortByYear, sortByMonth), sortByDay)

// is the same as...
nsort(sortByYear, sortByMonth, sortByDay)
```

---

**go nuts with `nsort`**

Now let's say we want to sort by an arbitrary number of factors. For example, sorting date objects requires three comparisons: `year`, `month`, and `day` -

```js
const { empty, map, reverse, nsort } =
  Comparison

const data =
  [ { year: 2020, month: 4, day: 5 }
  , { year: 2018, month: 1, day: 20 }
  , { year: 2019, month: 3, day: 14 }
  ]

const sortByDate =
  nsort
    ( map(empty, x => x.year)  // primary: sort by year
    , map(empty, x => x.month) // secondary: sort by month
    , map(empty, x => x.day)   // tertiary: sort by day
    )
```

Now we can sort by `year`, `month`, `day` -

```js
data.sort(sortByDate)
// [ { year: 2019, month: 11, day: 14 }
// , { year: 2020, month: 4, day: 3 }
// , { year: 2020, month: 4, day: 5 }
// ]
```

And just as easily reverse sort by `year`, `month`, `day` -

```js
data.sort(reverse(sortByDate))
// [ { year: 2020, month: 4, day: 5 }
// , { year: 2020, month: 4, day: 3 }
// , { year: 2019, month: 11, day: 14 }
// ]
```

Implementing N-sort is a breeze thanks to functional principles. Our `concat` and `empty` do all the hard work -

```js
const Comparison =
  { // ...
  , nsort: (...m) =>
      m.reduce(Comparison.concat, Comparison.empty)
  }
```

Expand the snippet below to see this code in action -

```js
const Comparison =
  { empty: (a, b) =>
      a < b ? -1
        : a > b ? 1
          : 0
  , map: (m, f) =>
      (a, b) => m(f(a), f(b))
  , concat: (m, n) =>
      (a, b) => Ordered.concat(m(a, b), n(a, b))
  , reverse: (m) =>
      (a, b) => m(b, a)
  , nsort: (...m) =>
      m.reduce(Comparison.concat, Comparison.empty)
  }

const Ordered =
  { empty: 0
  , concat: (a, b) =>
      a === 0 ? b : a
  }

const { empty, map, concat, reverse, nsort } =
  Comparison

const sortByDate =
  nsort
    ( map(empty, x => x.year)  // primary
    , map(empty, x => x.month) // secondary
    , map(empty, x => x.day)   // tertiary
    )

const data =
  [ { year: 2020, month: 4, day: 5 }
  , { year: 2019, month: 11, day: 14 }
  , { year: 2020, month: 4, day: 3 }
  ]

console.log(data.sort(reverse(sortByDate)))
// [ { year: 2020, month: 4, day: 5 }
// , { year: 2020, month: 4, day: 3 }
// , { year: 2019, month: 11, day: 14 }
// ]
```

---

**JavaScript modules**

Above `Comparison` and `Ordered` are defined as simple objects. JavaScript is a very flexible language and `import`/`export` syntaxes were made explicitly available for modularising your programs. Writing modules in this way gives us a clear picture of where things should go and provides us with plenty of room to grow our code -

```js
// Comparison.js

import { lt, gt, eq, concat:_concat } from "./Ordered"

const asc = (a, b) =>
  (console.log(a, b), a < b) ? lt
    : a > b ? gt
      : eq

const empty =
  asc

const map =  (m, f) =>
  (a, b) => m(f(a), f(b))

const concat = (m, n) =>
  (a, b) => _concat(m(a, b), n(a, b))

const reverse = (m) =>
  (a, b) => m(b, a)

const desc =
  reverse(asc)

export { asc, concat, desc, empty, map, reverse }
```

```js
// Ordered.js

const lt = 
  -1

const gt =
  1

const eq =
  0

const empty =
  eq

const concat = (a, b) =>
  a === eq ? b : a

export { concat, empty, eq, gt, lt }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the delta. Otherwise the callback returns `undefined` for each call.

```
arr2.sort(function(a, b) {
    return arr[b] - arr[a];
});
```

For adding the right order, you need ot take the index from `indices` to address the right element and assign `i` as style order value.

```js
function sort() {
    var array = [1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        z = document.getElementsByClassName("triable");

    [...array.keys()]
        .sort((a, b) => array[b] - array[a])
        .forEach((v, i) => z[v].style.order = i);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sort()">sort</button><br>
<div style="display: flex;">
<span class="triable">1</span>
<span class="triable">4</span>
<span class="triable">3</span>
<span class="triable">4</span>
<span class="triable">5</span>
<span class="triable">6</span>
<span class="triable">7</span>
<span class="triable">8</span>
<span class="triable">9</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: My actual array have a little bit more number, but the code is the same. When I tried to do :

arr2.sort(function(a, b) {
    return arr[b] - arr[a];
});

for descending array, that give me this sequence when I access arr by arr2 :
9, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 4, 1
and my initial arr was :
1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Comment: i don't ge the same result. pease see above.

Comment: Your code work very well for ascending sort, but it does not for descending sort (this is where I want to throw my computer in my window)

Comment: just exchange `a` and `b`.

Comment: @NinaScholz nice solution

Comment: This solution work very well for both ascending and descending sort, thank you a lot Nina for the help

Answer (score 0):

Much Code, but it works :)

**For sort ASC:**

```js
var test = [1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log("Original Array: " + test);
var len = test.length;
var indices = new Array(len);
for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) indices[i] = i;
indices.sort(function (a, b) { return test[a] < test[b] ? -1 : test[a] > test[b] ? 1 : 0; });
test.sort();
console.log("Sort-ASC " + test);
console.log("Index from Array " + indices);
```

**For sort DESC:**

```js
var test = [1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log("Originales Array: " + test)
var len = test.length;
var indices = new Array(len);
for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) indices[i] = i;
indices.sort(function (a, b) { return test[a] < test[b] ? -1 : test[a] > test[b] ? 1 : 0; });
indices.reverse();
test.sort();
test.reverse();
console.log("Sort-DESC " + test);
console.log("Index from Array " + indices);
```

Answer (score -1):

Its much easy buddy use this 
arr.sort(function(a, b){return a - b}); // use return otherwise it will not triggered and - + plus denote ascndng dcndng ordee
Simple method ..... Happy coding